# Forms with maps feature that allows users to set their location

Tags: forms, google-maps, dictionary, location, selection

I am looking for a online app or code to embed that allows a user to set a certain location on a map. 
What we need is a form in which a user inputs its name, address, email and his favorite location which can be a certain point in a town, a point of interest or an arbitrary place in the woods. We would like to see the map selection as well or the GPS coordinates of his selection. 
We thought about Google Maps but did not figure a way to achieve this. 
Do you have an idea how we can achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found something that is usable:

[Google Maps API Reverse Geocoding](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v2-geocoder-tool.html)